# featurizing images of different sizes

Tags: machine-learning, svm, image-processing

I'm training a non linear svm to do classification on images. I'm featurizing the image by creating 3 features for each pixel, its rgb value. My question is: How should i normalize images of different dimensions. My initial thought is to go through all the images and find the maximum width and height; then extend all the images to that width and height and fill its missing pixel values with -1's. Will a non-linear svm work ok with this image normalization? How do other people deal with images of different sizes?

Comment: You can do whitening: remove the mean and divide by standard deviation. Look at Yann LeCun papers for more details.

Comment: I just looked it up: it doesn't seem related. how does whitening make it so that all images end up having the same number of features? thanks for the help.

Comment: I asked the same question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37016276/cropping-scaling-imagenet-images  
I ended up using random crops and it seemed to work fine

Answer (score 2):

You can compare images with different number of features (arising from images of different sizes). [Pyramid Match Kernel](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/Image_Datasets/Caltech101/grauman_darrell_iccv05.pdf) does just that. It tries to measure the similarity between images that have different number of features. [The code is available on the internet](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jjl/libpmk/).

Answer (score 0):

I would be more worried about having images of different aspect ratios than images of different sizes. The way I would approach the problem would be to discard some of the images (the one who are abnormally small) and downscale all the other to a common size.
Why I did propose downsampling instead of upsampling the images? By upsampling you will be introducing a lot of noise and opportunity to overfit (high variance), downsampling will work the other way around... only on massive datasets do big images appear.

A personal recommendation: why use svm for image classification?
By my experience you would be much better suited with a [CNN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) classifier, it is better suited to capture the non-linearities that are common on this kind of tasks and they overfit much less, when used wisely of course.